# Interactive shell in Django

Tags: python, django, shell

I would like to get an interactive shell with the code, but I don't even know if such thing exits. Could anyone be able to help me at this point?

**EDIT :**

I already know we could use `python manage.py shell`, but I would like something we could insert in the code in such a way we do not have to re-import all the libraries in the shell.

Answer (score 9):

This command will help you to load all packages.

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

Reference link http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: you can use ptpython with this and that is so cool; just like `python manage.py shell_plus --ptpython`

Answer (score 3):

Try with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#shell

```
django-admin shell
```

Or

```
python manage.py shell
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not answer my question.

Comment: Not answer to question.

Answer (score 0):

root the django project then `python manage.py shell` do the views actions here.

Comment: Sorry, this is not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a pydev console in PyCharm, which can load anything you want, if you set up it in PyCharm's preferences.

Mine is here:

```
/Users/waryak/.virtualenvs/python3.8_django/bin/python3.8 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=49852
```